# Company Mode in All Buffers

Tags: init-file, company-mode

I'm trying to configure company-mode to activate in all buffers, with the appropriate back-ends depending on file-type. To that end, I've added the following to my `init.el` file. However, regardless of which file-type I open, company-mode does **not** automatically activate. Help in sorting this out is appreciated.

```
;; Enable global company mode
(require 'company)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
(setq company-idle-delay 0.1)
(setq company-minimum-prefix-length 1)
(setq company-backends '((company-capf company-files company-elisp company-inf-ruby company-anaconda company-go company-irony company-clang company-cmake company-css company-yasnippet) (company-dabbrev company-dabbrev-code)))
```

Complete init.el posted here: http://pastebin.com/eyvvzUPW

Comment: Your config seems OK, and can evaluate this in a scratch buffer and start getting auto-completions. Is it possible some other config is interfering -- can you start `emacs -Q` and then evaluate this and see if it works? You might also try a much setting for `company-backends` and see if you can get it working with one or two backends first.

Comment: @glucas I've added the complete init.el file for reference. Yes, I'm able to run `emacs -Q` and then execute the above included configuration successfully. Do you notice anything off in the complete init.el? Do you have any suggestions for debugging the init.el file?

Comment: Recursively bisect your init file to find the problem.  Do a quick search on this site for "bisect init", and a bunch of answers will pop up to explain how to do that.

Comment: You can use `(global-company-mode)` for activating `company` on all buffers. I recommend `customize-variable` instead of those `(setq …)`

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me. You should check if your custom.el is setting any additional `company-` variables. As Dan noted, the way to debug is to bisect your init file.